# Java code coming up with error

Tags: java, list, constructor, arraylist, nullpointerexception

When the I try and add and order (which has previously been created with the Order class) to the `waitingList` I get this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DeliveryLog.addOrder(DeliveryLog.java:41)
```

I'm using BlueJ to write my Java code.

Here is the code :

```
import java.util.*;
/**
* Write a description of class DeliveryLog here.
* 
* @author Stefan Lazic
* @version 1
*/
public class DeliveryLog
{  
  private Date logDate;
  private int numberOfOrders;
  private ArrayList<Order> waitingList;
  private ArrayList<Order> deliveredList;

 /** constructor 
 * @param dd day
 * @param mm month
 * @param yy year
 */
 public DeliveryLog(int dd, int mm, int yy)
 {
    //Initialses the log date and sets the default order value to 0
    logDate = new Date (dd,mm,yy);
    numberOfOrders = 0;
    ArrayList<Order> waitingList = new ArrayList<Order>();
    ArrayList<Order> deliveredList = new ArrayList<Order>();
 }

 public int getCallIns(int dd, int mm , int yy)
 {
   return numberOfOrders; 
 }

 public int getOrdersWaiting()
 {
   return waitingList.size();
 }

 public void addOrder (Order order)
 {
   waitingList.add(order);

 }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have re-declared the list references in your constructor: -

```
ArrayList<Order> waitingList = new ArrayList<Order>();
ArrayList<Order> deliveredList = new ArrayList<Order>();
```

The above statement creates two local list references in the constructor, whose scope is limited to it, and initializes them. So, it is not actually initializing the list reference  declared as `instance variable`.

Now the `list` reference used in `DeliveryLog.addOrder()`, are the one declared as `instance variables` which are still not initialized.

**Change the above two initialization in constructor to: -**

```
waitingList = new ArrayList<Order>();
deliveredList = new ArrayList<Order>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
ArrayList<Order> waitingList = new ArrayList<Order>();
ArrayList<Order> deliveredList = new ArrayList<Order>();
```

To this:

```
waitingList = new ArrayList<Order>();
deliveredList = new ArrayList<Order>();
```

You are creating two local variables called `waitingList` and `deliveredList`, which shadow the attributes of the same name - so you're initializing local array lists, not the attributes as intended, and the attributes themselves remain `null`, which cause the NPE.

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor, you re-declared waitingList and deliveredList.

You should change your constructor to look like this:

```
public DeliveryLog(int dd, int mm, int yy)
 {
    //Initialses the log date and sets the default order value to 0
    logDate = new Date (dd,mm,yy);
    numberOfOrders = 0;
    this.waitingList = new ArrayList<Order>();
    this.deliveredList = new ArrayList<Order>();
 }
```

Otherwise your instance variables waitingList and deliveredList will remain uninitialized, and when you call the addOrder method, it will throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

The variables you use inside the DeliveryLog method are not the ones you declared in the class. Hence the variable "waitingList" declared in the class remains uninitialised. Change:

```
ArrayList<Order> waitingList = new ArrayList<Order>();
ArrayList<Order> deliveredList = new ArrayList<Order>();
```

to

```
waitingList = new ArrayList<Order>();
deliveredList = new ArrayList<Order>();
```

in the method and you should be good.